# Random operators

Tags: probability-theory, operator-theory, random

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$ be a probability spaces and $H$ be a Hilbert space. By a random operator $A$ from $H$ to $H$ we mean a linear continuous mapping from $H$ into the Frechet space $L_0^H (\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$ of all $H$-valued random variables. My question is: How Can we define $|A|$ and the adjoint $A^*$?